# selecting distinct values in mysql from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables, `tbl_first_product`, `tbl_third_product` and `tbl_fourth_product`.

Each table having `size1`, `size2`, `size3`, `size4`, `size5` columns.

for example, in `tbl_first_product`

```
id    size1    size2    size3    size4    size5

1      38       40       42       43        44
2      28       30       32       34        40
```

in `tbl_third_product`

```
id    size1    size2    size3    size4    size5

1      30       32       40        0        0
2      28       30       32       34        0
```

in `tbl_fourth_product`

```
id    size1    size2    size3    size4    size5

1      20       26       40       44        0
2      28       30       32       34        40
```

I want to combine all these tables and get distinct values, And the output should be,

`20 26 28 30 32 34 38 40 42 43 44`

Is there any method to get this output using mysql and php.

I tried a lot. But no result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do UNION of each field and `SELECT DISTINCT` from it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT value
    FROM
   (SELECT size1 AS value FROM tbl_first_product

    UNION

    SELECT size2 AS value FROM tbl_first_product

    UNION

    SELECT size3 AS value FROM tbl_first_product

    UNION

    SELECT size4 AS value FROM tbl_first_product

    UNION

    SELECT size5 AS value FROM tbl_first_product

    UNION

    SELECT size1 AS value FROM tbl_third_product

    UNION

    SELECT size2 AS value FROM tbl_third_product

    UNION

    SELECT size3 AS value FROM tbl_third_product

    UNION

    SELECT size4 AS value FROM tbl_third_product

    UNION

    SELECT size5 AS value FROM tbl_third_product

    UNION

    SELECT size1 AS value FROM tbl_fourth_product

    UNION

    SELECT size2 AS value FROM tbl_fourth_product

    UNION

    SELECT size3 AS value FROM tbl_fourth_product

    UNION

    SELECT size4 AS value FROM tbl_fourth_product

    UNION

    SELECT size5 AS value FROM tbl_fourth_product) T
    WHERE value <> 0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The above code is working. How to remove `0` from result.

Comment: You can use `WHERE` Right? :)